# How to fix the Cannot POST /index.html error?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

The below is the example of calculator app with HTML and Javascript.

When I execute the program with nodemon, access the `localhost:3000`, and push the submit button, the error is shown on the browser(Google Chrome).

```bash
[nodemon] starting `node calculator.js`
Server started on port 3000.
```

### Error Message

There is no error when executing the program, so how I can find the fixing points?

```
Cannot POST /index.html
```

### Code

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Calculator</h1>
    <form action="/" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="n1" placeholder="First Number">
        <input type="text" name="n2" placeholder="Second Number">
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Calculate</button>
    </form>
    
</body>
</html>
```

calculator.js

```js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true})); //store the numbers in the forms

app.get("/", function(req, res){
   res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html"); //relative path
});

app.post("/", function(req, res){

    var num1 = Number(req.body.n1);
    var num2 = Number(req.body.n2);
    console.log(num1, num2); //no results shown

    var result = num1 + num2;
    res.send("The result of the calculation is " + result);
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Server started on port 3000.");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested the code and there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with it.

Some reasons why it might not be working for you:

1. Might have turned off auto-save in `VSCode`
2. An application might be interfering with your code (some browser extentions are known to cause this)
3. Something is wrong with the paths.

Auto Save can be turned back on by going to `File`, then checking `Auto Save`.
To verify it is not something wrong with the paths, you could edit your question to include an image of your directory so we could help you further.